# How to add HTML dependencies in an update* function for custom Shiny Input

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have a custom Shiny Input (`MyInput`), which lets you include an icon. 
The icon can be updated in an `updateMyInput` function.

Everyhing works fine, if an icon was given initially. But if the initial icon is NULL, and an icon is added with `updateMyInput`, it does not work since the dependencies are not added.

I tried to use the `Shiny.renderDependencies` in JS without success.
First I had to add the dependencies to the icon object like this, otherwise it was not passed to JS.

```
icon$htmldeps <- htmltools::htmlDependencies(icon)
```

Then in JS I did

```
Shiny.renderDependencies(data.icon.htmldeps)
```

which adds the stylesheets with a wrong **href** (undefined):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="undefined/css/v4-shims.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="undefined/css/all.min.css">
```

What is the correct way of adding the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your dependencies explicitly in your `myInput` function :

```
# With htmltools >= 0.3.5
iconInput <- function(inputId, icon) {
  tags$div(
    id = inputId,
    icon,
    htmltools::findDependencies(shiny::icon("home"))
  )
}

# With htmltools < 0.3.5
iconInput <- function(inputId, icon) {
  htmltools::attachDependencies(
    x = tags$div(
      id = inputId,
      icon
    ), 
    value = htmltools::findDependencies(shiny::icon("home"))
  )
}
```

From server-side you can try :

```
icon$htmldeps <- shiny::createWebDependency(
  htmltools::resolveDependencies(
    htmltools::findDependencies(
      shiny::icon("home")
    )
  )[[1]]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but that desnt really solve my problem I think. As I said, when I pass an icon initially it works fine.. Just when icon initially is `NULL`, it doesnt work. So I am wondering how can I attach the dependencies in an update* Function, that uses `session$sendInputMessage`?

Comment: If you're only using FontAwesome icons from Shiny, it will solve your problem since the dependency will be attached independently of the icon provided.

Comment: Yes, for now I am just using FA-icons.. but also the `createWebDependency` doesnt work. Do I have to do something special in the `receiveMessage` JS-part?

Comment: Try `Shiny.renderDependency` instead of `Shiny.renderDependencies` or wrap result of `createWebDependency` inside a `list`

Comment: Wrapping in a list did work!! `Shiny.renderDependency` is not a function, I just see `renderDependencies`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool! ah yes `renderDependency` isn't exported